# Is It Another Letter? No! It's an Email

Tags: story

I was checking all my emails when all of a sudden, 1 particular email just popped on my screen. I decided to take a look at that

> Hello, I'm Mr. XYZ
>
> Sorry tu say thiz but your son hes been kidnapped by me of course. If you want them bacc, you heve to zust find them yourself. Since I em a really nice berson, I will give you e himt :
>
> 123 456 789 100391
>
> P.S. : Sorry for the mispellings. I em not gud in english Bwahahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change the misspelled letters to correct letters.
>  
>  Now, reading the fixed letters, you get `osaka japan` 
>  
>  Your kid is in Osaka, Japan.

Note: (Not sure)

> The number is a red herring.

Comment: Correct! That's why I just put the story tag